# Export Python Code from Orange

Tags: python, orange

Since Orange is just running Python code under the hood...is it possible to set up and do my analysis in Orange but then export or output the underlying code for documentation or replication?

Comment: Your query seems to be a duplicate of [Feature Request: Workflow -> Python Script option?](https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/1341). The progress, unfortunately, appears to have stalled.

Answer (score 2):

Since I was also looking for it just yesterday being a newbie,sharing what I found , As per Orange FAQ it says

[image: Orange FAQ]

and it directs to the link @K3---rnc mentioned.

But i found similar request as well not sure how well it works-

[Orange Data Mining load saved models](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/37250/orange-data-mining-load-saved-models)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598627/orange-save-model-in-python-script

Answer (score 0):

It appears this is not possible at the moment due to the way Orange is structured.  Apparently, each widget would need to have code written for its export separately which would be a lot of work.

It's basically discussed here on their github: https://github.com/biolab/orange3/issues/1341

Answer (score -2):

A common complaint about Python’s syntax is that it’s impossible to generate Python code on the fly, from a program.
If you want, use Rcmdr (R pkg) to do your analysis and machine learning. You can export the output AND THE CODE. 
I use since long time the two languages. Python is powerful but it has this black point.

Comment: Common Complaint?  What?