# Orange Data Mining load saved models

Tags: data-mining, orange

I am planning to use the Orange Data Mining Tool for easy data exploration and model generation. What is still unclear to me is: after finding a good model, what can I do with it, how can I use or deploy it in production?

I already found out that there is no Orange server which can run the Orange workflow. But is it at least possible to load the model in Python and use it there which was generated and saved via the Orange UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is what the `Save Model` widget does under the Model tab. Create your model, then click save model and your model will be saved to a [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/pickle.html) file. Then just load your pickle file in Python.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45598627/orange-save-model-in-python-script) is a similar question on Stack Overflow:

[image]